# Getting Roblox Avatar image by username

Tags: python, discord.py, roblox

Today, I was making a Discord bot in Python that will put users in a queue. I want an image of their Roblox avatar as a Discord embed.

I've tried to do this with the code below, but no embed was sent after the command:

```py
api_url = f'https://api.roblox.com/users/get-by-username?username={roblox_username}'

                response = requests.get(api_url)

                data = response.json()

                if 'errorMessage' in data:

                    await message.channel.send('User not found or API error.')

                    return

                user_id = data['Id']

                avatar_url = f'https://www.roblox.com/Avatar-thumbnail/image?userId={user_id}&width=420&height=420&format=png'

                # Create and send the embed with the Roblox user's avatar

                embed = discord.Embed(title=f"{roblox_username}'s Roblox Avatar", color=0x00ff00)

                embed.set_image(url=avatar_url)

                await message.channel.send(embed=embed)

            except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:

                await message.channel.send('An error occurred while fetching the avatar. Please try again later.')

                print(f'Error: {e}')
```

Comment: is there an error msg occuring?

Comment: No error messages

Comment: the code is completely fine with no errors . I dont know where the problem is arising

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @nischalsharma maybe i provide the enite code, maybe something before it makes the embed not sendable

Comment: @TOPUD you can give the entire code but i dont know if i would be able to solve your problem or not.... however, i can try

Comment: @nischalsharma when I went into the website it doesn't exist maybe you know what website could get it

Answer (score 0):

According to this, your endpoint has a typo (it's avatar-thumbnails, with an -s) https://github.com/matthewdean/roblox-web-apis#thumbnail-apis.

There is also another endpoint at /v1/users/avatar if some features are  poorly documented or unavailable on the one you are using - https://thumbnails.roblox.com/docs/index.html